# Setting InstallShield INSTALLDIR from registry

Tags: installation, registry, installshield

I'm working on a Basic MSI project in InstallShield 2012 Pro.

I'm trying to set the `INSTALLDIR` property with the value of a registry key with no success.

1. I've tried to set the property with the full registry path as per [this page](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/isxhelp18/ExpressTaskSettingINSTALLDIRfromReg.htm), but when running the installation, it's recognized as a network path and fails
2. I've created a System Search to get the registry value and store it in a property, but when setting `INSTALLDIR` to `{MY_REGISTRY_PATH}`, it also fails.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Best regards, Julio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you logged the installer?  Does AppSearch return a value?

For what it's worth, you can't change INSTALLDIR ( or any directory property ) once it has clients ( components ) installed.  What I do is

AppSearch ->  INSTALLDIRFOUND
Type 51 Set Property CA SetINSTALLDIR = INSTALLDIRFOUND condition Not INSTALLDIR and INSTALLDIRFOUND and Not Installed

This ensures that the custom action only fires during the initial ( or major upgrade ) context and only if INSTALLDIRFOUND has a value and INSTALLDIR was not passed at the command line.

This needs to be scheduled for both the UI and Execute sequences.

Comment: Great. Creating a CS SetProperty type did it for me. Thanks